# python, matplotlib.animation: My 'planets' aren't rotating?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

My planets are not rotating in my plot and im not entirely sure why?

As a side note, is there way to scale the planets radius properly with respect to the sun. And could the initial positions(x,y) be the aphelion distance from the sun? But no worries, no need to answer, just looking form some insight. Thank you.

```
from pylab import* 
from matplotlib.animation import *

earth_radius = 6.3781e6#meters earth radius
suns_radius = 696e6#meters suns radius 
mercury_radius = 2439.5e3# meters mercury radius 
venus_radius = 6052e3 #meters venus radius

SunEarth_dist = 152e9 #distance from sun to earth approx. 1Au = 152e6km
SunMercury_dist = 69.8e9 #meters
SunVenus_dist = 108.9e9#meters


sun_mass = 1.988e30 #m1 : kg
mercury_mass = .330e24#m2: kg 
venus_mass = 4.87e24 #m3 : kg 
earth_mass = 5.97e24#m4 : kg


#radius of the planets scaled from the sun
r1 = suns_radius
r2 = mercury_radius
r3 = venus_radius
r4 = earth_radius
n = 10000#number of steps
dt = 10000#step size 
G = 6.67384*10**(-11)#gravitational constant


def planets():
    tmax = dt* n 
    t = 0
    x = 0
    #inital position of the planets
    x1 = 3844e8*0.8*0
    y1 = 3844e8*0.8*0
    x2 = 3844e8*0.8
    y2 = -3844e8*0.8*0
    x3 = -3844e8*0.8
    y3 = 3844e8*0.8*0
    x4 = -3844e8*0.8*0
    y4 = -3844e8*0.8
    #intial velocity of each planet

    Velocity_xS = 0
    Velocity_yS = 0
    Velocity_xM = 800
    Velocity_yM= 1700
    Velocity_xV = 0
    Velocity_yV = -1500
    Velocity_xE = 2000
    Velocity_yE = 0

    #distance between the planets
    d12 = sqrt((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2)
    d23 = sqrt((x2-x3)**2+(y2-y3)**2)
    d13 = sqrt((x1-x3)**2+(y1-y3)**2)
    d14 = sqrt((x1-x4)**2+(y1-y4)**2)
    d24 = sqrt((x2-x4)**2+(y2-y4)**2)
    d34 = sqrt((x3-x4)**2+(y3-y4)**2)
    while t < tmax:
        Fg12 = (G*sun_mass*mercury_mass)/d12**2
        Fgx12 = -Fg12*((x1-x2))/d12
        Fgy12 = -Fg12*((y1-y2))/d12

        Fgx21 = -Fg12*((x2-x1))/d12
        Fgy21 = -Fg12*((y2-y1))/d12

        Fg13 = (G*sun_mass*venus_mass)/d13**2
        Fgx13 = -Fg13*((x1-x3))/d13
        Fgy13 = -Fg13*((y1-y3))/d13

        Fgx31 = -Fg13*((x3-x1))/d13
        Fgy31 = -Fg13*((y3-y1))/d13

        Fg23 = (G*venus_mass*mercury_mass)/d23**2
        Fgx23 = -Fg23*((x2-x3))/d23
        Fgy23 = -Fg23*((y2-y3))/d23

        Fgx32 = -Fg23*((x3-x2))/d23
        Fgy32 = -Fg23*((y3-y2))/d23

        Fg14 = (G*sun_mass*earth_mass)/d14**2
        Fgx14 = -Fg14*((x1-x4))/d14
        Fgy14 = -Fg14*((y1-y4))/d14

        Fgx41 = -Fg14*((x4-x1))/d14
        Fgy41 = -Fg14*((y4-y1))/d14

        Fg24 = (G*sun_mass*earth_mass)/d24**2
        Fgx24 = -Fg24*((x2-x4))/d24
        Fgy24 = -Fg24*((y2-y4))/d24

        Fgx42 = -Fg24*((x4-x2))/d24
        Fgy42 = -Fg24*((x4-x2))/d24

        Fg34 = (G*sun_mass*earth_mass)/d34**2
        Fgx34 = -Fg34*((x3-x4))/d34
        Fgy34 = -Fg34*((y3-y4))/d34

        Fgx43 = -Fg34*((x4-x3))/d34
        Fgy43 = -Fg34*((y4-y3))/d34

        Acceleration_xS = Fgx12/sun_mass + Fgx13/sun_mass + Fgx14/sun_mass
        Acceleration_yS = Fgy12/sun_mass + Fgy13/sun_mass + Fgy14/sun_mass

        Acceleration_xM = Fgx21/mercury_mass + Fgx23/mercury_mass + Fgx24/mercury_mass
        Acceleration_yM = Fgy21/mercury_mass + Fgy23/mercury_mass + Fgy24/mercury_mass

        Acceleration_xV = Fgx32/venus_mass + Fgx31/venus_mass + Fgx34/venus_mass
        Acceleration_yV = Fgy32/venus_mass + Fgy31/venus_mass + Fgy34/venus_mass

        Acceleration_xE = Fgx41/earth_mass + Fgx42/earth_mass+ Fgx43/earth_mass
        Acceleration_yE = Fgy41/earth_mass + Fgy42/earth_mass + Fgx43/earth_mass

        Velocity_xS = Velocity_xS +Acceleration_xS*dt
        Velocity_yS = Velocity_yS +Acceleration_yS*dt

        Velocity_xM = Velocity_xM +Acceleration_xM*dt
        Velocity_yM = Velocity_yM +Acceleration_yM*dt

        Velocity_xV = Velocity_xV +Acceleration_xV*dt
        Velocity_yV = Velocity_yV +Acceleration_yV*dt

        Velocity_xE = Velocity_xE +Acceleration_xE*dt
        Velocity_yE = Velocity_yE +Acceleration_yE*dt

        #update the position of the planets 
        x1 = x1 + Velocity_xS*dt
        y1 = y1 + Velocity_yS*dt


        x2 = x2 + Velocity_xM*dt
        y2 = y2 + Velocity_yM*dt

        x3 = x3 + Velocity_xV*dt
        y3 = y3 + Velocity_yV*dt

        x4 = x4 + Velocity_xE*dt
        y4 = y4 + Velocity_yE*dt

        Sun.center = x1,y1
        Mercury.center = x2,y2
        Venus.center = x3,y3
        Earth.center = x4,y4

        d12 = sqrt((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2)
        d23 = sqrt((x2-x3)**2+(y2-y3)**2)
        d13 = sqrt((x1-x3)**2+(y1-y3)**2)
        d14 = sqrt((x1-x4)**2+(y1-y4)**2)
        d24 = sqrt((x2-x4)**2+(y2-y4)**2)
        d34 = sqrt((x3-x4)**2+(y3-y4)**2)
        t = t+dt

        return x, t

def initial_points(planets):
    x, t = planets[0], planets[1]
    line.set_data(t, x)
    ctr = Sun.center
    ax.set_xlim(ctr[0]-5e12, ctr[0]+5e12)
    ax.set_ylim(ctr[1]-5e12, ctr[1]+5e12)
    return line

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-5e12, 5e12), ylim=(-5e12, 5e12))
ax.set_aspect("equal")
line, = ax.plot([], [], '', ms=10)



Sun = Circle((0,0), r1, fc='yellow')
ax.add_artist(Sun)

Mercury = Circle((0 ,0), r2, fc='brown')
ax.add_artist(Mercury)

Venus = Circle(( 0,0), r3, fc='green')
ax.add_artist(Venus)

Earth = Circle((0,0), r4, fc='red')
ax.add_artist(Earth)


ani = FuncAnimation(fig, initial_points, planets, blit=False,\
     interval=10, repeat=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know matplotlib, but your `planets` function resets the bodies' positions to their starting positions each time it's called. You should try to simplify `planets` - it has [lots of repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), which makes it hard to read and can be a source of bugs.

Comment: Your `return` is encased into the `while` loop inside planets, which means it will return before the condition is satisfied at a first glance. Also you're resetting the position each time? Should there a `while` loop in the first place? Just looking at the documentation it looks like it should just update each frame (whereas you're looping through and updating it inside that function multiple times, which gets called each frame). But I'm not familiar with `FuncAnimation` so I might be wrong on that point.

Comment: Also, I recommend that at this stage you don't worry about the gravitational forces between the planets, just try to get it working right using only the forces between the sun and each planet, treating the sun as a fixed point. You can improve the accuracy by using the bodies' [standard gravitational parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter) rather than G and their masses.

Comment: (cont) Then you should look into using a better integration method. You're currently using [Euler integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method), but that rapidly accumulates errors, unless the time step size is tiny. It would be better to use a symplectic integrator, like [leapfrog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration) or  [verlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration).